# Extracting integers from a string

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Imagine I have a block of text that contains words and numbers. I want to extract all the integers from the text. Thus, if the input is

```
"Now is the time for all good men to come 2 the aid of their country"
```

the correct output should be `2` (or `{2}`).

Given the input

```
"1 is looking for 25 people to eat 3.14159"
```

the correct output should be `{1, 25}`.

I have been working through a complex process with `Characters[]` and `Select[]`, but I think a much simpler solution must be possible.

Comment: `Cases[ToExpression /@ 
  StringCases[string, 
   NumberString], _Integer]`

Comment: `"Here's 1. Is it 1 or 1. ?"`

Comment: @Kuba That would be an integer. march's solution is good but misses that one.

Comment: Define integer then, `MatchQ[1., _Integer]` is not enough.

Comment: `"Is 3/2 less than 2 or 3? How about -1, what can be done?"`

Answer (score 4):

You can get this result by mixing `StringExpression` with `RegularExpression`.

Regular expressions have the ability to perform a negative look-ahead. This can be used to insure that no numbers which have a decimal followed numbers are matched.

```
getIntegers[s_String] := 
 StringCases[ s,
  (StartOfString | Whitespace) ~~ u : Repeated["-", {0, 1}] ~~ 
   n : DigitCharacter .. ~~ RegularExpression["(?![\\./]\\d)"] :>
    (If[u == "-", -1, 1] FromDigits@n)]
```

Then

```
getIntegers["1 is looking for 25 people to eat 3.14159"]
(* {1, 25} *)

getIntegers["Here's 1. Is it 1 or 1. ?"]
(* {1, 1, 1} *)

getIntegers["Is 3/2 less than 2 or 3? How about -1, what can be done?"]
(* {2, 3, -1} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I approve, but the purpose of my comment above was to force OP to consider other possibilities; your result may or may not be what he actually wants.